# Converting QList to QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qlist, qvariant

The class contains this:

`Q_PROPERTY(QList<double>  switch1  READ switch1 WRITE setSwitch1 NOTIFY switch1Changed)`

```
void setSwitch2(QList<double> arg)
{
    if (m_switch2 != arg)
    {
        m_switch2 = arg;
        emit switch2Changed(arg);
    }
}
```

The below works:

```
setSwitch2(QList<double>::fromVector(QVector<double>::fromStdVector(data->switch2)));
```

but now my datatype is `QVariantList` instead of `QList<double>`.

**How should I replace QList with QVariant now?**

This doesn't work:

```
setSwitch1(QVariantList::fromVector(QVector<QVariant>::fromStdVector(data->switch1)));
```

Comment: The body of you question does not make sense after reading the title. It does not even have a QVariant anywhere.

Comment: It does have a QVariantList. Actually I want the C++ array to be accessible from QML, hence I wanted to replace QList with QVariant or QVariantList (whichever of them works)  @LaszloPapp

Comment: Actually, QList is already available from QML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this constructor:

> [QVariant::QVariant(const QList & val)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariant-24)
>
> Constructs a new variant with a list value, val.

I.e. when storing a QList as a QVariant, the template type of the QList has to be a type that is OK for QVariant. There is no other constructor or conversion method for this.

You should be writing this:

```
QVariant variant(
    QList<double>::fromVector(QVector<double>::fromStdVector(data->switch2))
);

setSwitchVariant(variant);
```

Comment: @user462608: your code does not show the whole context, but this is the only way of the conversion. I am not sure what you mean by "what should I replace with what?".

Comment: Due to QList being a class template it is just not possible to have
a generic constructor (as proposed in the accepted answer) for QVariant from a QList. Constructing such QVariant can be achieved with QVariant::fromValue(). Although the result will be a QVariant containing a QList<QVariant>.

Comment: In addition to what StefanQ wrote, there is in fact no `QVariant(const QList &)` constructor (that's not even valid syntax since QList needs a type). There is one specifically for a `QList<QVariant>` but that is not the same thing. Qt cannot determine that the `double` in this case can be converted to QVariant. So the suggested code throws a compile error (at least with Qt 5.9+): "cannot convert argument 1 from 'QList<qreal>' to 'QVariant::Type'".

Comment: PS. Further details about this/related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158034/qlist-in-qvariant-qvarianttype-returns-weird-type/58178040#58178040

Answer (score 1):

If no need constructor:

```
QList<QUrl> params;
QVariant varParams;
varParams.setValue<QList<QUrl>>( params );
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that it is not relevant for the author. But maybe someone will come in handy.

```
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<double>>("Stuff");
QList<double> lst;
// convert
QVariant varLst = QVariant::fromValue(lst);
// back
lst = varLst.value<QList<double>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the QVariant constructor for lists: QVariant(const QList &list)
and the typedef QVariantList. Both togheter in a nice template:

```
template <class T> static QVariant toVariant(const QList<T> &list)
{
    QVariantList variantList;
    variantList.reserve(list.size());
    for (const auto& v : list)
    {
        variantList.append(v);
    }
    return variantList;
}
```