# QList in QVariant, QVariant::type() returns weird type

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I'm trying to store `QList<int>` in `QVariant` and then do a typecheck to determine exact type of value stored in `QVariant` (for serialization).
`QVariant::type()` works fine with scalar types like `int` or `QString`, but this is what I got with `QList<int>`:

```
QList<int> list{1,2,3};
QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue<QList<int>>(list);
qDebug() << v.type() << "|" << v.typeName() << "|" << v.userType() << "|" << QVariant::typeToName(v.type());
```

Produces:

```
QVariant::QWidget* | QList<int> | 1030 | QWidget*
```

Where this `QVariant::QWidget*` even came from? I can't find it in QVariant's `enum Type`, nor value 1030. `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<int>);` has no effect.

What's wrong here? Or should I use `typeName()` since it returns correct type name instead of `type()`?

Qt 5.13.1, clang 8.0.1, Linux 64-bit

Comment: It's just an observation: If only the `core` or `gui` module is included I get: `QVariant::QList<int> | QList<int> | 1024 | QList<int>`, but if you add `widgets` I get: `QVariant::QWidget* | QList<int> | 1025 | QWidget*`

Comment: It's simply returning the last registered `QMetaType` there (1024 is start of "user" range). Another point of confusion, for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QList<T>` isn't really a pre-defined variant type (except `QList<QVariant>`) so it technically resolves to a `QMetaType::UserType`.  It's a bit convoluted to follow, and definitely depends on which Qt modules have been included (the meta type system is designed to be expandable this way -- eg. w/out GUI module you wouldn't have any of those types available).

So... it's actually `QMetaType` that "knows" about the underlying custom types. From given example `QVariant::typeToName(v.userType())` prints `QList<int>` correctly. I've found that `QVariant::userType()` always returns the actual meta type, whereas just `type()` seems fairly useless (even the docs are convoluted trying to explain how it works).

To add to the confusion, `QVariant::Type` seems to be deprecated... if you click the "QVariant::Type" link in the [docs for `type()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#type) it goes to the "obsolete members" section. Where that enum isn't even listed.

Actually `QMetaType` doesn't "know" the `QList<int>` type either until it is used (or registered).  Example:

```
    qDebug() << QMetaType::type("QList<int>");  // prints 0
    QList<int> list{1,2,3};
    QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(list);
    qDebug() << QMetaType::type("QList<int>");  // prints 1028 on my test project, yours may vary
```

Or, if registered specifically:

```
    qDebug() << qRegisterMetaType<QList<int> >("QList<int>");  // prints 1028
    qDebug() << QMetaType::type("QList<int>");  // prints 1028
    QList<int> list{1,2,3};
    QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(list);
    qDebug() << QMetaType::type("QList<int>");  // still 1028
```